# Inability to Install Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

Okay, Microsoft has been giving such a headache with this. I am attempting to Dual-boot Ubuntu 14.04LTS onto my HP Envy Touchsmart, model 4-1105dx. I created the partition (I have a GPT-kind partitions table). I've followed every guide I can find about to disable SecureBoot and change my UEFI settings. My computer won't allow me to disable UEFI so I enabled Legacy Boot and still, no matter what I have done, whenever I go to install Ubuntu, when I get to the 'Installer Type' page, I get an empty table and no options to change anything. It does not show me my partitions, doesn't give me any options. Nothing. I'm at my wits end. Am I just missing something or am I doomed to Windows forever?

Comment: HP specific bios/uefi info: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03801890&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en#N536

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue recently with dual booting a computer. In my research the best option was to re install windows using legacy boot instead of UEFI, then install Ubuntu alongside windows.

Disable UEFI in your bios and install windows to your hard drive, erasing the contents of the current drive (back your files up before doing this). When installing windows you have the choice of setting how much disc space to use, you can change this later if you want as well. After windows is installed, insert your Ubuntu cd/usb and select install alongside windows.

Maybe others will chime in with a solution to your problem, but it was easier for me to do it this way.

Plus you get rid of UEFI and all the bloatware that came with your machine ;)